# Python: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 350

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've got this error using the MySQL db backend for django.

The query I'm trying to execute (it worked perfectly with MariaDB connector):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT a.*, COALESCE( NULLIF(a.aa_change_ref_gene, '.'), NULLIF(a.gene_detail_ref_gene,'.') ) AS variant, b.*, c.* FROM `db-dummy`.specimen_genome_data c JOIN `db-dummy`.genome_info a ON a.record_id = c.genome_id JOIN `db-dummy`.specimen_data b ON b.record_id = c.specimen_id WHERE a.gene_name LIKE concat(?, '%') ORDER BY a.gene_name LIMIT 30", (gene,))
```

What I've tried:

Basically replacing the `'%'` for `"%"` and `'%%'`

Then I am getting this error for the `"%"` case:

> Exception Type:   TypeError
> Exception Value:
> not all arguments converted during string formatting

And this error for the `'%%'` case:

> Exception Type:   ProgrammingError
> Exception Value:
> not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
> Exception Location: /home/prime/.env/intervar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute, line 203

Comment: Did you change the query at all? The first error complains about a `'` at the 350th character in the query but the query provided is only 343 characters.

Comment: Yeah for security reasons I changed some names, but basically it's complaining about `'%'` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not use `?` for the parameterization, rather it uses format string style parameters, i.e. `'%s' % 'hello'`, etc. See [Passing parameters into raw [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw).

It looks like you want to make a query of the form `LIKE '<SOMETHING>%'`, firstly do not use `?` (use `%s` instead), next instead of trying to concatenate in the query concatenate in *python* itself.

Hence you query should be like (Truncated irrelevant parts):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ... a.gene_name LIKE %s ORDER BY ...", ('{}%'.format(gene),))
```