# Django - Passing multiple parameters into raw queries with %s format

Tags: python, mysql, django

In the project I am working on before we used a custom connector for MariaDB but now I have to use the default connector for MySQL in Django.

The previous MariDb connector used `?` For parameterization but MySQL for Django uses `%s` instead.

With the MariaDB you could something like this:

```
sd_query = create_update_query(interpretation, record_id, tableName)
cursor.execute(sd_query, tuple(interpretation.values()) )
```

how to do it with a `%s` parameterization?

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation.

Comment: Why create a raw query and not use the ORM?

Comment: I am not allowed to use ORM in this case.

Comment: Okay... is there a specific error you are getting with what you have tried?

Comment: @IainShelvington Updated the question with further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how to prepare the SQL then it's a Python specific question, not Django.
You can do something like this-

```
update_query = "UPDATE `db-dummy`.s_data SET s_id = {}, h_loss = {} WHERE record_id = {}"    
update_query = update_query.format(s_id_value, h_loss_value, 5877)
```

Now, if you want to execute it in Django you need to import cursor from connection.

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Then execute it with-

```
cursor.execute(update_query)
```

If your SQL statement returns something then you can use

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

Then you will be able to loop through the 'records' variable.

Comment: Repeat after me: Making queries using String formatting / concatenation is **BAD**. It makes you **vulnerable** to **SQL Injection**.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused with the solution I had given you in your *previous* [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731834/python-unsupported-format-character-0x27-at-index-350), there I had used `'{}%'.format(some_value)` because you had a value and wanted to make a LIKE query with it (`<SOME_VALUE>%`), so I had performed that string formatting to make the string of the proper needed form. You don't need to do that here, you can simply pass the tuple, hence what you do here would be the same as what you did with your MariaDB cursor, with the only difference being you use `%s` instead of `?` in the placeholders:

```
sd_query = create_update_query(interpretation, record_id, tableName)
sd_data = tuple(interpretation.values())
cursor.execute(sd_query, sd_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal python string formating is not enough for this task, someone could try to do a query injection, I mean, the posibility still there (even if you secured the query sintax). Django already takes care of this for you so you don´t have to think too much about it, check this part of Django Docs [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#s-passing-parameters-into-raw).